# Change Program Flow based on Available Libraries

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am developing a Python model that will support graphing if the correct modules are installed.  I would like the source code to be the same if possible, IE, if the graphing model can't load, graphing would be ignored from the menu logic.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Attempt an import and set a flag if fails.  Then use the flag to determine whether to offer graphic output:

```
try:
    import Tkinter
    gui_installed = True
except ImportError:
    gui_installed = False


...

result = somecalc()
if gui_installed:
    display_with_gui(result)
else:
    display_as_text(result)
```

Comment: And with this, I shouldn't get an error with the display_with_gui not being found, because it would only try to load that function if Tkinter exists, right?

Comment: That's correct.  Python uses call-by-name which is lookedup only when  a function is called.  The job of the if-statement is to make sure the call can only happen when the appropriate library successfully imported.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can wrap an `import` statement in a `try`-`except` block.  It is commonly used for backwards-compatability cruft.  For instance, by importing a fall-back module as the desired module.  That way the rest of the code can be oblivious to which module is actually in use.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a flag as [suggested by @Raymond Hettinger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863224/python-change-program-flow-based-on-available-libraries/7863243#7863243) you could set to `None` the actual name that provides optional capabilities:

```
try: import Tkinter
except ImportError:
    display_with_gui = None
else:
    def display_with_gui(): # use Tkinter here
        pass

result = somecalc()
if display_with_gui:
    display_with_gui(result)
else:
    display_as_text(result)
```